# How to escape special characters in Oracle Data Pump

Tags: oracle, datapump

Environment

Oracle 19c on Linux

```
cat export_schema.par

DIRECTORY=USER_CLONE
DUMPFILE=export_user.dmp
schemas=USER@YAHOO.CA
```

**The export fails with "USER" not found error.**

Somehow, @ and anything beyond it is ignored.

I tried the "" escape character as follows.

```
DIRECTORY=USER_CLONE
DUMPFILE=export_user.dmp
schemas=USER\@YAHOO.CA
```

**The export fails with "USER@YAHOO.CA" not found error.**

Any suggestions how I can escape "@" in the par file or from the command line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this schema name coming from? Oracle schema/user names typically cannot contain "@" characters. From the documentation:

> Nonquoted identifiers can only contain alphanumeric characters from your database character set and the underscore (_).

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA

Using double quotes on usernames and other identifiers to force the use of other special characters is not recommended, as it would not be compatible with most client applications, and would force *any* reference to the schema to be enclosed in double quotes for any usage. In an application like Data Pump where schema names may be offset with double quotes regardless, it may not be possible to have such characters.

Comment: We have enabled AD authentication in the database. Users use their Windows login credentials to access the database.  Hence email-like oracle IDs. I get frequent requests for new user creations and I am looking into automating the user cloning process.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your username is "USER@YAHOO.CA"? It could also your external name if you e.g. use Kerberos authentication.
Try to get your username like this:
`SELECT USERNAME FROM USER_USERS`

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

```
    oracle@msk script]$ sqlplus / as sysdba
    
    SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Fri Oct 1 17:38:41 2021
    
    Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
    
    
    Connected to:
    Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
    With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
    
    SQL> create user "USER@YAHOO.CA" identified by "T@ger";
    
    User created.
    
    SQL> grant connect, resource to "USER@YAHOO.CA";
    
    Grant succeeded.
    
    SQL> alter user "USER@YAHOO.CA" account unlock;
    
    User altered.
    
    SQL> grant read,write on directory DATA_PUMP_DIR to "USER@YAHOO.CA";
    
    Grant succeeded.
    
    SQL> grant DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE to "USER@YAHOO.CA";
    
    Grant succeeded.
    
    SQL>




more exp_dp_yahoo.sh
#!/bin/bash


I=`date +"%d-%m-%y"`
NAMEDUMPFILE=yahoo.dmp.$I
PARFILE=/u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_yahoo
LOG=/u02/script/parfile_expdp_log.log

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/expdp  parfile=$PARFILE  DUMPFILE = $NAMEDUMPFILE  2>$LOG

more  /u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_yahoo


USERID = \"USER@YAHOO.CA\"/\"T@ger\"@orastb3
#    username/password
SCHEMAS    = \"USER@YAHOO.CA\"
DIRECTORY = DATA_PUMP_DIR
CONTENT=ALL
FLASHBACK_TIME=SYSTIMESTAMP


Export: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Oct 1 17:56:21 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Starting "USER@YAHOO.CA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01":  "USER@YAHOO.CA"/********@orastb3 parfile=/u02/script/parfile_expdp_stroy_yahoo dumpfile=yahoo.dmp.01-10-21.
Estimate in progress using BLOCKS method...
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE_DATA
Total estimation using BLOCKS method: 0 KB
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/PRE_SCHEMA/PROCACT_SCHEMA
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/TABLE
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/COMMENT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/INDEX
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/CONSTRAINT/CONSTRAINT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/INDEX_STATISTICS
Master table "USER@YAHOO.CA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
******************************************************************************
Dump file set for USER@YAHOO.CA.SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01 is:
  /u01/app/oracle/admin/orastb3/dpdump/yahoo.dmp.01-10-21
Job "USER@YAHOO.CA"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01" successfully completed at Fri Oct 1 17:56:32 2021 elapsed 0 00:00:11
```